# Standard text size for Android custom big notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I'm creating some notifications for my app. I have a custom notification with a text and a part of a picture. I'd like the text to have the same font and size and style of other notifications text, but it does not and I wasn't able to find any documentation about notifications text size.
Could anybody help?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It will vary by Android OS version, and I cannot rule out the possibility that device manufacturers might mess with it. You can find layouts for notifications in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/.../data/res/layouts/`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you installed the Android SDK and `...` is an installed platform for some API level.

Answer (score 0):

If your android version is 2.3 or more use:

Primary text: 
android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title

Secundary text:
Use the style android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent

And i recommend read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView)